# URL redirect page w/ POST, use JavaScript or C#

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, redirect

I need to create a simple service that accepts some query string parameters, fires off a POST to a service that accepts some of those parameters then, redirects to a different page that is specified in the query string.

My quandary is whether to use C# or JavaScript, basically whether to use an aspx page with the code behind in the on_load function or just some quick JavaScript on an HTML page. Performance in this case is my main concern I want it to appear seamless.

Thoughts or suggestions?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are performing a "fire and forget" POST, then the javascript method will work great because the HTTP call will happen async.  So, you can fire off the call and then change the browser location.

If you need to wait for the result, the performance of either of these methods will not make a big difference.  However, the javascript method will allow you to more easily influence the UI while waiting.